# Erode islands of pixels while polygonizing a raster

Tags: python, raster, gdal, vector, polygonize

I am polygonizing a single band raster.

[image]

I am using gdal.Polygonize() function to vectorize the raster.

```
img= r"C:\Users\aoi2.tif"
src_ds = gdal.Open(img)
srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

# create output datasource
dst_layername = "output"

drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource(dst_layername +".shp")
src = osr.SpatialReference(wkt=prj)

dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs = src)

gdal.Polygonize( srcband, srcband, dst_layer, -1, [], callback=None )

del src_ds, srcband, dst_ds, dst_layer
```

output shapefile looks like:

[image: polygonized]

My aim is to erode the islands of pixels smaller than 3 pixels and keep the rest, how can I do that?

Comment: Gdal_sieve is made for that purpose https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_sieve.html#gdal-sieve.

Answer (score 2):

Two options for me :

- You can do it directly on your raster using `connectedComponentsWithStats` of `opencv` and `CC_STAT_AREA` option. See this link ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857055/sorting-all-connected-components-by-area-and-exporting-them-fails-how-to-resolv)).
- You can do it on your shapefile. First, you have to calculate a new field "area" for your shapefile, then, you can do an attribute query and delete features under a specific value (area = 3 pixels in your case).

In this case, here, a function to calculate the polygon area in meters:

```
def polygon_area(shp):
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    src = driver.Open(shp, 1)
    layer = src.GetLayer()
    layer.GetFeatureCount()

    new_field = ogr.FieldDefn("Area", ogr.OFTReal)
    new_field.SetWidth(32)
    new_field.SetPrecision(2)
    layer.CreateField(new_field)

    for feature in layer:
        geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
        area = geom.GetArea()
        feature.SetField("Area", area)
        layer.SetFeature(feature)
```

Here, a function to delete the features under a specific value:

```
def sort_by_area(shp, area):
    layer = shp.GetLayer()
    layer.SetAttributeFilter(area)

    for feature in layer:
        layer.DeleteFeature(feature.GetFID())
        shp.ExecuteSQL('REPACK ' + layer.GetName())
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the best way to remove such artifacts is to use Shrink-Expand technique.

QGIS supports this via SAGA/GRASS (eg. https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/r.grow.shrink.html). You need to shink your areas by 1 pixel and then expand it back by 1.

After shrink you get rid of small thin areas, after expand back you get initial slightly smoothed boundaries of remaining polygons.

Working with grid data is much-much faster then with vector, so I highly recommend you to clean up raster first and then convert it to ready-to-use vector layer.